# How do I get an app, threadedcomments_extras, to show up or be ignored?

Tags: python, django, social-networking, pinax, threaded-comments

I'm getting:

```
ImportError at /
No module named threadedcomments_extras
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://stornge.com:8000/
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named threadedcomments_extras
Exception Location: /home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /home/jonathan/virtual_environment/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/jonathan/clay/apps',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pinax/apps',
 '/home/jonathan/clay',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
Server time:    Mon, 25 Mar 2013 13:59:14 -0400
```

There's something in the media/apps directory that looks to me like a Django app:

```
(virtual_environment)jonathan@li393-189:~/clay$ find . | grep -i threadedcomments
./media/apps/threadedcomments_extras
./media/apps/threadedcomments_extras/__init__.pyc
./media/apps/threadedcomments_extras/templatetags
./media/apps/threadedcomments_extras/templatetags/comments_tag.pyc
./media/apps/threadedcomments_extras/templatetags/comments_tag.py
./media/apps/threadedcomments_extras/templatetags/__init__.pyc
./media/apps/threadedcomments_extras/templatetags/__init__.py
./media/apps/threadedcomments_extras/__init__.py
./media/projects/intranet_project/templates/threadedcomments
./media/projects/intranet_project/templates/threadedcomments/comments.html
./media/templates/default/threadedcomments
./media/templates/default/threadedcomments/comments.html
(virtual_environment)jonathan@li393-189:~/clay$
```

However, copying the media app to ./apps/ kills the worker thread immediately. So does commenting out 'threadedcomments_extras' in settings.py.

How can I get either threadedcomments_extras installed and working, or remove all expectation of threadedcomments_extras?

Thanks,

Comment: Where is it imported?

Comment: Breadcrumb remark: I made this post as part of a concerted effort to get a Pinax 0.7.3 social project to work with a more recent version of Pinax (for reasons beyond me, the social project in Pinax 1.0.0 is a bare stub, complete with lorem ipsum in the final page). It took me a lot of digging to get to Pinax 0.7.3 (there are innumerable places advertising a free Pinax 0.7.3 download, but I tried dozens and they all pointed to a pinaxproject.com (now) 404. Having found Pinax 0.7.3 and wanting to save other programmers the headache, I have made it available at http://JonathansCorner.com/pinax